# Send array from field to javascript and then to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im stuck with a ajax function im creating. Here is the deal, I have a form that i am sending to php via ajax. In my form i have another form that is uploading images and stores the url in a new created inputfield array. My problem is i dont know how to send these new fields to the php from ajax/jquery

here is some of the code

The uploaded file is working great and i get a new field from every uploaded file into my existing form.

```
<input name="img[]" type="hidden" value="mynewfile1.jpg">
<input name="img[]" type="hidden" value="mynewfile2.jpg">
etc...
```

Im declaring the other form objects like this and then sends them to my php file like this

**Declaring**

```
var event_title = $('input[name=event_title]');
var event_tags = $('input[name=event_tags]');
```

//This is my array im also trying to send to php but how?

```
var event_img = $('input[name=img[]]');
```

**Sending**
This is done by regular ajax via POST method.

```
var data = 'event_title=' + event_title.val() etc...
```

**My php**

```
$event_title =  $_POST['event_title'];
$event_url =  $_POST['event_url'];
etc..
```

Here im getting the stuff from ajax and then using the variables to post and do other stuff.

Im getting the image array like this

```
if ($_POST['event_img']) {

  $array=$_POST['event_img'];
  foreach ( $array as $value ) {

etc...
```

My guess is that the problem lies in the sending from ajax, how do i fetch a array field declare it in javascript and send it to php and handle it there?

Thanks for any thoughts and help!!

Comment: I'm just curious, how are you uploading the files, are you using uploadify? I'm not sure what effect using img[] as the input name will have on the jQuery, can you select 'img' without brackets? If you are using Firebug (and you should be) try debugging to the console: console.log(event_img). Also, since $('input[name=img[]]') returns an array of elements, are you iterating through that to get the individual field values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the entire form and send it on with ajax

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

then if you send data with your ajax, all the current form data will be available as if you actually submitted the form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would i reach the variables in php? 
Is it same as before?
$event_title =  $_POST['event_title']; where event_title is the field name like this - <input size="50" id="event_title" type="text" name="event_title" class="text" />

Comment: exactly, BUT note that you cannot upload files via ajax.

Comment: I tried it out and im getting all my fields into place except the img[] array field where the array is created from the uploaded files. Im not uploading with the sending form. The upload is allready made and the uploaded file url is stored in a field with the name img[] 

im trying to reach the array in the php like this 

if ($_POST['img[]']) {
  $array=$_POST['img[]'];
  foreach ( $array as $value ) {

Comment: Its working now!! I removed the [] from img in my array and its working like a charm! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

use json:
encode your array as json via the `JSON.stringify` function, and on the server side I think the `json_decode` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AJAX to upload files through file input form fields asynchronously which means that in order for your files to be available to PHP through the **$FILES** array you need to actually submit the form (either manually or by using the **.submit()** method).

If you do need to upload the files with your AJAX requests you need to use tools such as Uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) etc. or create a proper client-server stream based upload system (which should not be such an easy task).